# Reledmac critical footnote without lemma

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, lemma

I am working on a transcription originally done with EDMAC over 25 years ago, so I am updating the markup as I go.

I need to be able to reproduce many line-numbered critical footnotes which have no lemma. That is, the lemma in the text at the point of attachment is *not* reproduced in the note, nor is the square bracket separator, only the reading.  Currently I am using this construction (in this example, on line 7):

```
ba rimhe\edtext{}{\Bfootnote[nosep]{reímhe}} gach deor lena
```

which gives the footnote "7    reímhe" with horizontal white-space where the absent lemma would have been. Is there a convenient way to suppress the additional space? (ie before I start writing an additional form of the \edtext macro).

This may appear perverse, but I am assured that the original editor had sound linguistic reasons (which I have not yet discovered) for some instances of the apparatus using "normal" critical footnotes with both lemma and reading, and for some of them omitting the lemma as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a horizontal space of 1em is added if no separator is printed.

You can set it using `\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator` hook.

Also a 0.5em space is added after line number, which can be set with `Xafternumber`. So if you want to have no space at all after the 1, do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
\Xafternumber{0pt}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{}{\Bfootnote[nosep]{reímhe}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you — I had failed to see that one. I need the .5em space, but it needs to be unbreakable, otherwise the line number may fall at the end of the line and the reading at the start of the next line.

Comment: Use `Xnonbreakableafternumber` to make it unbreakable.